# I need solution for TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str' programming

Tags: python

Question is below

Q) There are several distance metrics for K-Means such as euclidean, squared euclidean and Manhattan. compare the purity score of k-means clustering for different distance metrics and Select the best distance matrix

This is my code for this

```
#separating the class and feature matrix
y = df2.num
X = df2.iloc[:,:-1]


from pyclustering.samples.definitions import FCPS_SAMPLES
from pyclustering.cluster.center_initializer import kmeans_plusplus_initializer
from pyclustering.cluster.kmeans import kmeans, kmeans_visualizer
from pyclustering.utils.metric import distance_metric, type_metric

def purity_score(clusters_label):
    clustering_classes_2 ={
        0: [0,0,0,0,0],
        1: [0,0,0,0,0],
        2: [0,0,0,0,0]
    }
    for cluster in range(ln(y)):
        for i in clusters_label[cluster]:
            clustering_class_2[cluster][y[i]] += 1
            purity = (max(clustering_classes_2[0])+max(clustering_classes_2[1])+max(clustering_classes_2[2]))/len(y)
            return purity
        
#Preparing initial centroids using K-Means++ method.
initial_centroids = kmeans_plusplus_initializer(X, 5).initialize()
print(initial_centroids)

#K-mean with the Euclidean metric
euclidean_metric = distance_metric(type_metric.EUCLIDEAN)
kmeans_instance_euclidean = kmeans(X, initial_centroids, metric=euclidean_metric)
kmeans_instance_euclidean.process()
clusters_euclidean = kmeans_instance_euclidean.get_clusters()
final_centroids_euclidean = kmeans_instance_euclidean.get_centers()
print(f"Purity score of k-means with EUCLIDEAN metric is{round(purity_score(clusters_euclidean)*100, 2)}%")
```

but I got this error

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_30352/1303550090.py in <module>
     17 
     18 #Preparing initial centroids using K-Means++ method.
---> 19 initial_centroids = kmeans_plusplus_initializer(X, 5).initialize()
     20 print(initial_centroids)
     21 

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'
```

could someone suggest the solution for this? Thank you

Comment: Code is missing. What is `X`?

Comment: sorry. now I add it. @Bharel

Comment: Ok... now we'd need to know what is `df2`....

Comment: ```df2```  is my dataset @ex4

Comment: Yes, that is easy to quess.... but what is in your dataset? Is data integers or strings? I quess strings and that is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation in https://pyclustering.github.io/docs/0.8.2/html/db/de0/classpyclustering_1_1cluster_1_1center__initializer_1_1kmeans__plusplus__initializer.html class `kmeans_plusplus_initializer` takes list of points as a first argument in constructor. You give variable `X`. It probably has string(s) instead of expected datatype.

I cannot find how this variable is defined in your code example. But my best bet is that there is your problem.

In documentation example of generate of expected data is like this:

```
# Read data 'SampleSimple3' from Simple Sample collection.
sample = read_sample(SIMPLE_SAMPLES.SAMPLE_SIMPLE3);
# Calculate initial centers using K-Means++ method.
centers = kmeans_plusplus_initializer(sample, 4).initialize();
```

That read_sample method seems to read sample data from text file.

Comment: X and y are class and feature matrix @ex4

Comment: @patrick why are they missing from your question code?  How are we supposed to guess their definition?

Comment: I"m sorry. I declared it for the previous question. That's why I forgot to add it for  this @MarkRansom